# Autohotkey: replace key combination (but with timeout)

Tags: autohotkey

When I type, I want my script to replace:

```
"ab" to "x"
"ac" to "y"
"a[more than 300ms]b" - don't replace, just leave "ab"
```

So, it should replace only if time between "a" and "b"/"c" is less than 300ms

tried doing this:

```
a & b :: Send x
a & c :: Send y
```

But it obviously doesn't 'forgive' me any delay

Would be great to get any hints, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) is usually good for replacements. To add that delay, here's a simple thing I could come up with:

```
~*a::APressTime := A_TickCount

:*B0:ab::
    if(A_TickCount - APressTime <= 300)
        SendInput, % "{BS 2}x"
return
```

First a simple hotkey for <kbd>A</kbd> that just saves the current system time with [`A_TickCount`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TickCount).

Then a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) to which I set some options you're likely going to want to use:
[`*`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Asterisk) so you don't need to type an [ending character](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars).
[`B0`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#b0) so it doesn't backspace the letters `ab` automatically.
You might also want to use the [`?`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Question) option so the hotstring also works while "inside of a word". Add it in if you want.

Then we compare the current system time to the time when a was last pressed. If it's 300ms or less, send backspace twice followed up by `x`.
([`{BS 2}`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key) is same as `{Backspace 2}` or `{Backspace}{Backspace}`)

To do the same with `ac`, just copy paste the hotstring again and switch `b` with `c`, and `x` with `y`.
Alternatively, here's something a bit more fancy to put them in the same hotstring label with a ternary:

```
:*B0:ab::
:*B0:ac::
    if(A_TickCount - APressTime <= 300)
        SendInput, % "{BS 2}" (SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0) = "b" ? "x" : "y")
return
```